# NodeJS parallel PostgreSQL query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I do not know why, but actually, it would have to be executed in parallel and only take 2 seconds:

```
const test = async () => {
  client.query("SELECT pg_sleep(2) FROM test", (err, result) => {
    console.log("DONE!");
  })
  client.query("SELECT pg_sleep(2) FROM test", (err, result) => {
    console.log("DONE!");
  })
  client.query("SELECT pg_sleep(2) FROM test", (err, result) => {
    console.log("DONE!");
  })
}
```

But this script needs 6 seconds. Why?

Im using the PostgreSQL database.

Thanks!

Comment: One `client` = one connection. I don't think a single connection support multiplexing/batching.

Comment: Btw, why are you using an `async` function but no `await` keyword anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making each request with the **same** client. It won't process the second one until it has finished the first.

You need to create [a pool of clients](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool) and get a new client for each of the three requests.